# Flex row not wrapping content on scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a table using flex divs and I'm having the problem that, when I scroll, the `row` does not wrap all the `items`

Before I scroll:

[image]

After I scroll:

[image]

Note that, because the `row` is red, I would expect it to properly wrap the items, which doesn't seem to happen when I scroll.

Any idea how to fix it?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/andrerpena/pen/RwLoRaJ

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
  .row {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    .item {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      width: 300px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: inline-flex instead of flex

Comment: @TemaniAfif I appreciate your answer. It works, except that, now, if you make `wrapper` wide-enough, rows will not work like rows (they will be inline)

Comment: I managed to solve it, using your solution by having row groups https://codepen.io/andrerpena/pen/RwLoRaJ

Comment: Thank you Tamini!